# Debugging a nasty SIGILL crash: Text Segment corruption

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, memory-corruption

Ours is a PowerPC based embedded system running Linux. We are encountering a random SIGILL crash which is seen for wide variety of applications. The root-cause for the crash is zeroing out of the instruction to be executed. This indicates corruption of the text segment residing in memory. As the text segment is loaded read-only, the application cannot corrupt it. So I am suspecting some common sub-system (DMA?) causing this corruption. Since the problem takes days to reproduce (crash due to SIGILL) it is getting difficult to investigate. So to begin with I want to be able to know if and when the text segment of any application has been corrupted. 
I have looked at the stack trace and all the pointers, registers are proper.  
Do you guys have any suggestions how I can go about it?

Some Info:   
Linux  3.12.19-rt30 #1 SMP Fri Mar 11 01:31:24 IST 2016 ppc64 GNU/Linux

(gdb) bt  
0  0x10457dc0 in xxx

Disassembly output:  
=> 0x10457dc0 <+80>:    mr      r1,r11  
   0x10457dc4 <+84>:    blr

Instruction expected at address 0x10457dc0: **0x7d615b78**   
Instruction found after catching SIGILL 0x10457dc0: **0x00000000**

(gdb) maintenance info sections  
0x10006c60->0x106cecac at 0x00006c60: .text ALLOC LOAD **READONLY** CODE HAS_CONTENTS

Expected (from the application binary):   
(gdb) x /32 0x10457da0  
0x10457da0 :       0x913e0000      0x4bff4f5d      0x397f0020      0x800b0004  
0x10457db0 :       0x83abfff4      0x83cbfff8      0x7c0803a6      0x83ebfffc  
0x10457dc0 :       **0x7d615b78**      0x4e800020      0x7c7d1b78      0x7fc3f378  
0x10457dd0 :       0x4bcd8be5      0x7fa3eb78      0x4857e109      0x9421fff0

Actual (after handling SIGILL and dumping nearby memory locations):  
Faulting instruction address: 0x10457dc0  
   0x10457da0 : 0x913E0000  
   0x10457db0 : 0x83ABFFF4  
=> 0x10457dc0 : **0x00000000**  
   0x10457dd0 : 0x4BCD8BE5  
   0x10457de0 : 0x93E1000C

Edit:
One lead that we have is that the corruption is always occurring at an offset that ends with 0xdc0.
For e.g.
Faulting instruction address: **0x10653dc0** << printed by our application after catching SIGILL
Faulting instruction address: **0x1000ddc0** << printed by our application after catching SIGILL
flash_erase[8557]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fed6dc0** nip 0fed6dc0 lr 0fed6dac code 30001
nandwrite[8561]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fed6dc0** nip 0fed6dc0 lr 0fed6dac code 30001
awk[4448]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fe09dc0** nip 0fe09dc0 lr 0fe09dbc code 30001
awk[16002]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fe09dc0** nip 0fe09dc0 lr 0fe09dbc code 30001
getStats[20670]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fecfdc0** nip 0fecfdc0 lr 0fecfdbc code 30001
expr[27923]: unhandled signal 4 at **0fe74dc0** nip 0fe74dc0 lr 0fe74dc0 code 30001

Edit 2: Another lead is that the corruption is always occurring at physical frame number 0x00a4d. I suppose with PAGE_SIZE of 4096 this translates to physical address of  0x00A4DDC0. We are suspecting couple of our kernel drivers and investigating further. Is there any better idea (like putting hardware watchpoint) which could be more efficient? How about KASAN as suggested below?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many servers are you running?  Does the SIGILL failure happen on one server, or multiple servers?  Is it possible to get the *physical* address of the corrupted memory?  How close to a page boundary are the addresses you're seeing?

Comment: It is seen on multiple servers. I will check how to get that info. Will have to try and reproduce the issue. Can you let me know what exactly we will check with the alignment to the page boundary?

Comment: The expected hex dump shows 16 bytes between 0x10457b0 and 0x10457dc0.  The actual only shows 4 bytes.  What is in the other 12 bytes?  Also between c0 and d0.  Maybe there is more to the overwrite than show.  Sometimes the value of the overwrite can give a clue e.g. a ASCII string.  Is there a reliable way to recreate the issue at the same address?  If so, you can put a watch point in the debugger and let it grind.

Comment: Yes in the actual hex dump only 4 bytes was printed. We have modified it to print all 16 bytes and would be re-running the test. It takes 2-3 days of automated testing to hit the problem. To give more details, our system has a separate DSP processor that uses DMA which is what we are suspecting right now. So we would be putting some guard code to check for memory addresses that it is writing to.

Comment: The challenge is that the issue is seen for any of the 5-6 applications that are running. So we will have to monitor the text segment of multiple applications. Our system does not have swap memory. Everything is loaded into RAM. So what we need is a way to monitor physical memory modifications for multiple address ranges. Is that even possible? Anyways, we'll first be checking if the DMA writes are occurring outside the valid range. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 4):

1.) Text segment is RO, but the permissions could be changed by [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), you can check that if you think it is possible

2.) If it is kernel problem:

- Run kernel with [KASAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kasan.txt) and KUBSAN (undefined behaviour) sanitizers
- Focus on drivers code not included in mainline
- The hint here is one byte corruption. Maybe i'm wrong, but it means that DMA is not to blame. It looks like some kind of invalid store.

3.) Hardware. I think, your problem looks like a hardware problem (RAM issue).

- You can try to decrease RAM system frequency in bootloader
- Check if this problem reproduces on stable mainline software, that is how you can prove that it's it

Comment: 1. No, we are not doing mprotect anywhere.  2. I see that KASAN is only available for x86, ours is PPC.  3. This problem has been observed on multiple setups, hence the chances of HW issues seems less. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As I wrote in above comment, we are suspecting DMA operations which should fall outside the purview of kernel related corruption. Will keep you posted.