# SIGILL because of "when the system has trouble running the handler for a signal"

Tags: c, linux

This is about a different SIGILL issue than what I had raised earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010931/debugging-a-nasty-sigill-crash-text-segment-corruption).
I understand the various reasons that can lead to a SIGILL and I have ruled out all of them except one that is mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html), which is,
"when the system has trouble running the handler for a signal".  Can somebody explain in what scenario can this occur? Where in the kernel can I see this code?

I have ruled out all other cases by looking at the instruction that was being executed when SIGILL was received. It is a harmless move register (mr) instruction. The stack frame is all proper with valid values of pc, sp, lr. Thanks.